# Installing nodejs and npm on MSYS2

Tags: node.js, msys2

My OS is win7, and I using MSYS2(version:MSYS_NT-6.1), Please give advice how to install nodejs and npm on this terminal, Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I found a solution for resolving the problem,

64bit env.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-nodejs
```

32bit env.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-nodejs
```

after installed, Open terminal

```
$ node -v
v6.11.0
```

Comment: In addition, `npm` is distributed with Node.js which means that when you download Node.js, you automatically get npm installed. Check with `$ npm -v `

Comment: For those wondering why node.exe is not in the msys2 path, you need to use the appropriate mingw console. (32/64-bit)

Comment: nodejs package is not available in msys packages (https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=pkg&q=nodejs)

Answer (score 11):

As of 2020, the package `mingw-w64-x86_64-nodejs` is not available any more. The simplest way to have *Node.js*, *npm* and *git* installed on a Windows machine is using the official Windows installers:

- Git: https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Node.js (*npm* is shipped with it): https://nodejs.org/en/download/

After installation, open a command prompt (click on start, and then type `cmd` and `[ENTER]`) and verify that all three tools are there:

```
git --version
node --version
npm --version
```

Later on, to update *Node.js*, simply reinstall it from the same source.

Comment: If you use another terminal such as Windows Terminal, you have to add `-full-path` option when starting `msys2_shell.cmd`. The `-full-path` option was not suggested for some reason in the official documentation at https://www.msys2.org/docs/terminals/

Comment: Did you use the Windows installer for this?

Comment: This doesn't work.  My MSYS terminal is "different" from windows cmd, and running cmd in the MSYS terminal, then npm within _it_ and still the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

I wasted a lot of time on this. My solution is:

- Download the Windows Binary (.zip) from nodejs site (https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
- Extract it to some folder
- Add that folder to the `PATH` env variable

Comment: While with this solution, the .npmrc file would be generated in C:\Users\tom instead of in the $HOME of msys2 shell, how to remedy it?

Answer (score 2):

It *does* work to use the Windows installer, and Node.js helpfully provides bash-script versions of `npm` and `npx` in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` to help streamline the process.

However, contrary to Cerclanism's comment @ jmgonet's answer, you should **not** use `--full-path` with MinGW, no matter what terminal you're using, since that will by default bring the **entire** Windows path into your MinGW environment.

(Assuming you're a typical Windows developer with things like MSVC, Windows Python, and etc. install dirs on your path, containing plenty of names that clash with MinGW path members, you can see how that might bite you at some point down the road. My full Windows CMD.exe `%PATH%` is 1236 characters! I don't want all that sucked into MinGW.)

Instead, you should add the nodejs install dir to your *MinGW* shell `$PATH`, say by using everyone's favorite `~/.profile`/`~/.zprofile` `$PATH`-munging trick:

```sh
# Append node.js to path
case ${PATH} in
  *"/c/program files/nodejs"*)
    ;;
  *)
    export PATH="$PATH:/c/program files/nodejs:"
    ;;
esac
```

You'll probably also want to set some configuration, since by default Windows `npm` will use `${APPDATA}/npm` for `prefix`, `${LOCALAPPDATA}/npm-cache` for `cache`, `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` for `shell`, etc.

```sh
# To view the full config including all defaults and overrides
npm config ls -l
# To view the active config for the specified environment
npm config list -L {global,user,project}
```

Maybe I was just confused, but to me it *seemed*, from what the configs show/say, that setting `prefix=` in my user config would override even **local** installs. (The project-specific ones where you `npm install` without `--global`, directly into a `node_modules` subdir of the current dir.) But after testing, happily I can report that's not the case, so it's safe to override the builtin `prefix=` from your `$HOME/.npmrc`.

Whether or not you move the `cache=` or let it stay at `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\` is your call. I'm sure it'll *work* that way. (Well, maybe not from an MSYS shell, but from MinGW it should be fine.)

There are minor differences I haven't overcome, but the only one that comes to mind right now is:

1. `npm help <command>` opens a browser window to HTML documentation, instead of displaying man page content directly in the terminal like it does on Linux. (Makes sense, as I don't think the manpages are even installed on Windows. Still disconcerting, though.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply install **nvm**, then install **nodejs** through there. In your MSYS2 shell just run the following to download and install nvm. Its better to go directly [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating) and copy the download commands as the version numbers will change in the url.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

**or**

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

then run the following to setup **nvm** on your bash path:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

After running those commands you can use `nvm install 16` or whatever node major version number you want. Type just `nvm` to get a list of available commands.