# Installing npm on msys2 terminal on windows 10 workstation

Tags: npm, windows-10, msys2

I have installed nodejs and npm works on Windows powershell as well as cmd. But, when I tried the command npm on msys2, it doesn't work. How do I link msys2 with the currently installed npm on Windows 10?

Comment: I had a similar problem like this right now with git lol It seems that the msys2 environment is different from Windows'. You can use `pacman` to install the packages you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473196/installing-nodejs-and-npm-on-msys2
I already tried this, but it says "As of 2020, the package mingw-w64-x86_64-nodejs is not available any more"