# Install Node.js under MSYS2 (2022)

Tags: node.js, msys2

I've Node.js + NPM installed in Windows (using the official MSI installer). The path containing their executables is both on system and user `PATH` environment variables. When I run `node` in MSYS2 it's not recognized.

Other things I considered:

- I did try `pacman -Ss nodejs` on MSYS2, and it outputs nothing.
- Update `/home/USER/.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` with:

```
export PATH=${PATH};"C:/Program Files/nodejs";
```

Yet Node.js commands aren't recognized. Another related question, [Installing nodejs and npm on MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46473196/19692949) (2017), has outdated answers which don't solve my problem.

Notes:

- I did restart the terminal after `PATH` changes.

Comment: Doesn't MSYS2 use linux-style PATH format internally? It should be `${PATH}:/c/Program Files/nodejs`, I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, yes, I thought Windows paths should work. That solved my problem!